# Regular expression for a string with special symbol

Tags: regex, string

I need to write a regex in c++ to match a string starts with the symbol ( and ends with the symbol ). The string has some letters and digits e.g,

```
(forwardmsg m22 l323 l221)
```

i have created this regular expression but it does not work

```
  \b\(forwardmsg\s+m\d+\s+l\d+\s+l\d+\)
```

Comment: You are matching exactly. That's not a regex for string enclosed in `( )`.

Answer (score 1):

`\b\(`

Open parens are not word boundaries.  Get rid of the `\b`.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please accept it (with the green check).

Comment: That's not a solution for _string enclosed within_ `( )`